# Tag Cloud Filter not working if Search results page has search signature

Tags: sxa

I am using `Sitecore 9.3 and SXA`, when I used the tag cloud it is working fine when the searchresults component in the search results page is not having signature but when I added signature it stopped working.

For more clarification, I have only one search result in my page with search signature "mysearchresults" and i am using the tag cloud in another page and when i click on the tag cloud it redirects me to :
**{Site URL}/Search#sxatags=tagtest** 
instead of : 
**{Site URL}/Search#mysearchresults_sxatags=tagtest**

in which the first URL is not working as it doesn't include search signature.

Comment: What does it mean "it stopped working"? Do you have any errors? What else you have on the page? Do other components also have signatures? You are checking search in preview mode? I could as much more questions. As you can see your question is not clear. Please fill it with more information about your setup.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski, i have added more clarification to my question so that it can help in explaining the issue